# Programs to create input for SQL database

Tags: html, mysql, css, sql, database

I am recreating an old database that's in MS Access with company data, contacts, conventions etc. but I have never done something like this. In the past few days I learnt to use MS Access and started recreating the tables to fit third form, creating table relationships etc.

But I got stuck when I started searching for a program/programs that could help me create an easy to use visual input form like in MS Access sparing me from having to delve into SQL and HTML.

I am not a native english-speaker so I couldn't really word what I wanted sufficient enough to find related google hits, I have found applications like Aptana Studio, Heidi SQL, Dreamweaver and so on. My question is, is there a program where I can manage the tables inside the database, create forms to input data with, all (if possible) wih a drag-and-drop designer?

I would be grateful for any number guides you guys have links for, because I just couldn't find what I wanted (possibly because of my still lacking programming expertise). Any guides touching on the topic of how to create input sites with HTML/CSS for an SQL database would also helpful if it's not possible to do without using these languages.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio, with SQL Server, has all of the features that you are asking for.  There are free versions of both, but with limitations.

You can also use a Java and MySQL solution.  To manage the database, use MySQL Workbench.  For an IDE that has a drag-and-drop designer, use either NetBeans or Eclipse.  For more information on either, google "Netbeans form designer" or "Eclipse form designer."

Answer (score 0):

For creating and managing databases you can use the "Sql Server management studio" itself.

If you have MS office, you can use "InfoPath" to create forms and connect them to the Sql Server database. Check this link out which shows how to do it :

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4246/data-entry-for-sql-server--building-quick-efficient-data-input-forms-using-infopath/